# Review implementation of stack by using array in C

Tags: c, array, stack

This question has become long after many updates. [Click here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/29183/review-implementation-of-stack-by-using-array-in-c#comment46116_29183) to go down.

---

I have implemented stack using arrays in C. Please give me suggestions on how to improve it. The purpose of writing it is practice-only.

I'll be implementing it by using pointers soon so please leave the part about using pointers instead of arrays for implementing stack.

**I'll keep adding updated code so please review the latest one.**

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

#define MAX_SIZE 100
#define MIN 1
#define MAX 3

void intro();

void push(int *arr, int *length, int data);
int pop(int* arr, int *length);

int main()
{
    int arr[MAX_SIZE];
    int length = 0;

    int choice = MAX + 1;
    int data;

    while (1)
    {
        while (MAX < choice || choice < MIN)
        {
            system("cls");
            intro();
            printf("Enter your choice -> ");
            scanf("%d", &choice);
        }

        system("cls");
        switch (choice)
        {
        case 1:
            printf("\nEnter data to be pushed -> ");
            scanf("%d", &data);
            push(arr, &length, data);
            printf("\nData pushed");
            break;
        case 2:
            printf("\nPopped Data is %d", pop(arr, &length));
            break;
        case 3:
            return 0;
        }
        printf("\nLength is %d", length);
        getchar();
        getchar();
        choice = MAX + 1;
    }
}

void intro()
{
    printf("1 Push data\n");
    printf("2 Pop Data\n");
    printf("3 Exit this program\n\n");
}

void push(int *arr, int *length, int data)
{
    if (*length == MAX_SIZE){
        printf("Stack Overflow\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    arr[(*length)++] = data;
}

int pop(int *arr, int *length)
{
    if (*length == 0){
        printf("Stack Underflow\n");
        exit(2);
    }
    return arr[--(*length)];
}
```

**Update 1 after Lstor gave suggestions**

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<errno.h>

static const int MAX_SIZE = 100;
static const int MIN = 1;
static const int MAX = 4;

void intro();

void push(int *, int *, int);
int pop(int *, int *);
int top(int *, int *);

int main()
{
    int arr[MAX_SIZE];
    int length = 0;

    for (;;)
    {
        int choice = MAX + 1;
        while (MAX < choice || choice < MIN)
        {
            system("cls");
            intro();
            printf("Enter your choice -> ");
            scanf("%d", &choice);
        }

        system("cls");
        int data;
        errno = 0;
        switch (choice)
        {
        case 1:
            printf("\nEnter data to be pushed -> ");
            scanf("%d", &data);
            push(arr, &length, data);
            if (errno == 1){
                printf("\nStack overflow");
            }
            break;
        case 2:
            data = pop(arr, &length);
            if (errno == 2){
                printf("\nStack underflow");
            }
            else{
                printf("\nThe data is %d", data);
            }
            break;
        case 3:
            data = top(arr, &length);
            if (errno == 1){
                printf("\nStack overflow");
            }
            else if (errno == 2){
                printf("\nStack underflow");
            }
            else{
                printf("\nThe data at top is %d", data);
            }
            break;
        case 4:
            return 0;
        }
        printf("\nLength is %d", length);
        getchar();
        getchar();
    }
}

void intro()
{
    printf("1 Push data\n");
    printf("2 Pop Data\n");
    printf("3 See the top of the stack\n");
    printf("4 Exit this program\n\n");
}

void push(int *arr, int *length, int data)
{
    if (*length == MAX_SIZE){
        errno = 1;
        return;
    }
    arr[(*length)++] = data;
}

int pop(int *arr, int *length)
{
    if (*length == 0){
        errno = 2;
        return -1;
    }
    return arr[--(*length)];
}

int top(int *arr, int *length)
{
    if (*length == 0){
        errno = 2;
        return -1;
    }
    else if (*length == MAX_SIZE){
        errno = 1;
        return -1;
    }
    return arr[*length - 1];
}
```

**Update 2** - Includes the suggestions by Lstor given in comments and William Morris's suggestions. I changed a few things and didn't implement William Morris's suggestion about user experience.

```
#include<assert.h>
#include<errno.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

static const int MAX_SIZE = 100;
enum action {PUSH = 1, POP, TOP, QUIT};

void clear_screen(void)
{
    system("cls");
}

static enum action get_user_action(void)
{
    int choice = 0;
    do
    {
        clear_screen();
        printf("%d Push data\n"
               "%d Pop Data\n"
               "%d See the top of the stack\n"
               "%d Exit\n\n"
               "Enter your choice -> ", PUSH, POP, TOP, QUIT);
        scanf("%d", &choice);
    } while (choice != PUSH && choice != POP && choice != TOP && choice != QUIT);
    return (enum action) choice;
}

void push(int *arr, int *length, int data)
{
    if (*length == MAX_SIZE){
        errno = PUSH;
        return;
    }
    arr[(*length)++] = data;
}

int pop(int *arr, int *length)
{
    if (*length == 0){
        errno = POP;
        return -1;
    }
    return arr[--(*length)];
}

int top(int *arr, int *length)
{
    if (*length == 0){
        errno = POP;
        return -1;
    }
    else if (*length == MAX_SIZE){
        errno = PUSH;
        return -1;
    }
    return arr[*length - 1];
}

int main(void)
{
    int arr[MAX_SIZE];
    int length = 0;

    enum action choice;
    while ((choice = get_user_action()) != QUIT)
    {
        clear_screen();
        int data;
        errno = 0;

        switch (choice)
        {
        case PUSH:
            printf("Enter data to be pushed -> ");
            scanf("%d", &data);
            push(arr, &length, data);
            if (errno == PUSH){
                printf("Stack overflow\n");
            }
            break;
        case POP:
            data = pop(arr, &length);
            if (errno == POP){
                printf("Stack underflow\n");
            }
            else{
                printf("The data is %d\n", data);
            }
            break;
        case TOP:
            data = top(arr, &length);
            switch (errno)
            {
            case PUSH:
                printf("Stack overflow\n");
                break;
            case POP:
                printf("Stack underflow\n");
                break;
            default:
                printf("The data at top is %d\n", data);
            }
            break;
        default:
            assert(!"You should not have reached this.");
        }

        printf("Length is %d\n", length);
        getchar();
        getchar();
    }
}
```

**Update 3** Includes William Morris's suggestions to Update 2

```
#include<assert.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

static const int MAX_SIZE = 100;
enum action {PUSH = 1, POP, TOP, QUIT};

void clear_screen(void)
{
    system("cls");
}

static enum action get_user_action(void)
{
    int choice = PUSH - 1;
    do
    {
        clear_screen();
        printf("%d Push data\n"
               "%d Pop Data\n"
               "%d See the top of the stack\n"
               "%d Exit\n\n"
               "Enter your choice -> ", PUSH, POP, TOP, QUIT);
        scanf("%d", &choice);
    } while (choice != PUSH && choice != POP && choice != TOP && choice != QUIT);
    return (enum action) choice;
}

void push(int *arr, int *length, int *status, int data)
{
    *status = PUSH - 1;
    if (*length == MAX_SIZE){
        *status = PUSH;
        return;
    }
    arr[(*length)++] = data;
}

int pop(int *arr, int *length, int *status)
{
    *status = PUSH - 1;
    if (*length == 0){
        *status = POP;
        return -1;
    }
    return arr[--(*length)];
}

int see_top(int *arr, int *length, int *status)
{
    *status = PUSH - 1;
    if (*length == 0){
        *status = POP;
        return -1;
    }
    return arr[*length - 1];
}

int main(void)
{
    int arr[MAX_SIZE];
    int length = 0;

    enum action choice;
    while ((choice = get_user_action()) != QUIT)
    {
        clear_screen();
        int status;
        int data;
        switch (choice)
        {
        case PUSH:
            printf("Enter data to be pushed -> ");
            scanf("%d", &data);
            push(arr, &length, &status, data);
            if (status == PUSH){
                printf("Stack overflow\n");
            }
            else{
                printf("%d pushed onto the stack\n", data);
            }
            break;
        case POP:
            data = pop(arr, &length, &status);
            if (status == POP){
                printf("Stack underflow\n");
            }
            else{
                printf("The data is %d\n", data);
            }
            break;
        case TOP:
            data = see_top(arr, &length, &status);
            switch (status)
            {
            case POP:
                printf("Nothing in the stack\n");
                break;
            default:
                printf("The data at top is %d\n", data);
            }
            break;
        default:
            assert(!"You should not have reached this.");
        }
        printf("Length is %d\n", length);
        getchar();
        getchar();
    }
}
```

**Update 4** After William Morris's comments on Update 3. I also made the whole thing use consistent bracing style suggested by Lstor in my question about [stack implementation by pointers](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/29213/review-implementation-of-stack-by-using-pointers-in-c)

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static const int MAX_SIZE = 100;
enum action {START, PUSH, POP, TOP, QUIT, END};

void clear_screen(void)
{
    system("cls");
}

static enum action get_user_action(void)
{
    int choice = START;
    do {
        clear_screen();
        printf("%d Push data\n"
               "%d Pop Data\n"
               "%d See the top of the stack\n"
               "%d Exit\n\n"
               "Enter your choice -> ", PUSH, POP, TOP, QUIT);
        scanf("%d", &choice);
    } while (!(START < choice && choice < END));
    return (enum action) choice;
}

void push(int *arr, int *length, int *status, int data)
{
    *status = START;
    if (*length == MAX_SIZE) {
        *status = PUSH;
        return;
    }
    arr[(*length)++] = data;
}

int pop(int *arr, int *length, int *status)
{
    *status = 0;
    if (*length == 0) {
        *status = 1;
        return -1;
    }
    return arr[--(*length)];
}

int peek(int *arr, int *length, int *status)
{
    *status = 0;
    if (*length == 0) {
        *status = 1;
        return -1;
    }
    return arr[*length - 1];
}

int main(void)
{
    int arr[MAX_SIZE];
    int length = 0;

    enum action choice;
    while ((choice = get_user_action()) != QUIT) {
        clear_screen();
        int status;
        int data;
        switch (choice) {
            case PUSH:
                printf("Enter data to be pushed -> ");
                scanf("%d", &data);
                push(arr, &length, &status, data);
                if (status == 1) {
                    printf("Stack overflow\n");
                } else {
                    printf("%d pushed onto the stack\n", data);
                }
                break;

            case POP:
                data = pop(arr, &length, &status);
                if (status == 1) {
                    printf("Stack underflow\n");
                } else {
                    printf("The data is %d\n", data);
                }
                break;

            case TOP:
                data = peek(arr, &length, &status);
                if (status == 1) {
                    printf("Nothing in the stack\n");
                } else {
                    printf("The data at top is %d\n", data);
                }
                break;

            default:
                assert(!"You should not have reached this.");
        }
        printf("Length is %d\n", length);
        getchar();
        getchar();
    }
}
```

**Update 5** After discussing things [in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/10569957#10569957) William Morris suggested other things. I have included Lstor's suggestion about using enum for status and suggestion in the chat.

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static const int MAX_SIZE = 100;
enum action {START, PUSH, POP, TOP, QUIT, END};
enum status {SUCCESS, FAILURE};

void clear_screen(void)
{
    system("cls");
}

static enum action get_user_action(void)
{
    int choice = START;
    do {
        clear_screen();
        printf("%d Push data\n"
               "%d Pop Data\n"
               "%d See the top of the stack\n"
               "%d Exit\n\n"
               "Enter your choice -> ", PUSH, POP, TOP, QUIT);
        scanf("%d", &choice);
    } while (!(START < choice && choice < END));
    return (enum action) choice;
}

enum status push(int *arr, int *length, int data)
{
    if (*length == MAX_SIZE) {
        return FAILURE;
    }
    arr[(*length)++] = data;
    return SUCCESS;
}

enum status pop(int *arr, int *length, int *data)
{
    if (*length == 0) {
        return FAILURE;
    }
    *data = arr[--(*length)];
    return SUCCESS;
}

enum status peek(int *arr, int *length, int *data)
{
    if (*length == 0) {
        return FAILURE;
    }
    *data = arr[*length - 1];
    return SUCCESS;
}

int main(void)
{
    int arr[MAX_SIZE];
    int length = 0;

    enum action choice;
    while ((choice = get_user_action()) != QUIT) {
        clear_screen();
        int data;
        switch (choice) {

            case PUSH:
                printf("Enter data to be pushed -> ");
                scanf("%d", &data);
                if (push(arr, &length, data) == SUCCESS) {
                    printf("%d pushed onto the stack\n", data);
                } else {
                    printf("Stack overflow\n");
                }
                break;

            case POP:
                if (pop(arr, &length, &data) == SUCCESS) {
                    printf("The data is %d\n", data);
                } else {
                    printf("Stack underflow\n");
                }
                break;

            case TOP:
                if (peek(arr, &length, &data) == SUCCESS) {
                    printf("The data at top is %d\n", data);
                } else {
                    printf("Nothing in the stack\n");
                }
                break;

            default:
                assert(!"You should not have reached this.");

        }
        printf("Length is %d\n", length);
        getchar();
        getchar();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a simple practice program like this, the user experience is perhaps not
something you considered much (more interesting is getting it to work :-) But
you should think about it in general.  Try using your program and consider
whether it is comfortable to use.  For example, if I want to enter many
numbers into the array, I have to repeatedly select `1` then enter the number,
select `1` then enter the number, etc.  This is tedious.  Added to that your
`getchar` calls at the end of each loop mean the user must type enter again,
without any purpose, the "Data pushed" message seems like noise, and if the
user has the patience to enter 100 numbers and dares enter another, the
program exits!

A better approach might be to allow several numbers to be entered at a time.
Or perhaps change the interface so that if the user types a number it is
pushed, if 'p' is typed, a number is popped and if 'q' the program exits.  If
the array is full, print a warning but don't exit.  These are just examples,
the point being that you should always think of the user.

---

One criticism I have of the coding is that your input choices are spread
throughout the file.  From `MIN`/`MAX` at the top through the choice-entry loop
and the switch statement to the `intro` function at the bottom.  There is
nothing tying these together and so if a change is made in one place you have
to remember to change every other location.

Adding an enum (or #defines) and using it everywhere would help:

```
enum action {PUSH, POP, QUIT};

static enum action get_user_action(void)
{
    int choice = 0;
    do {
        printf("%d Push data\n"
               "%d Pop Data\n"
               "%d Exit\n\n"
               "Enter your choice -> ", PUSH, POP, QUIT);
        scanf("%d", &choice);
    } while (choice != PUSH && choice != POP && choice != QUIT);
    return (enum action) choice;
}
```

and in `main`

```
enum action choice;
while ((choice = get_user_action()) != QUIT) {
    if (choice == PUSH) {
        // do the push
    } else {
        // do the pop
    }
}
```

---

Some minor points:

- Your `printf` statements often put a '\n' at the beginning of the text to be
  printed.  This is unusual - it would be better if you put the \n at the end.
- Your switch statement has no `default` case, which is generally bad practice.
  Always use a default.  In this case the switch is arguably not needed.
- Move `main` to the end to avoid the need for prototypes.  Although at first it
  might seem odd, this is a common pattern.
- Both `main` and `intro` need `void` parameter list

---

**Comments** on your 2nd update

I'm not keen on your setting `errno` as an error value.  And certainly not
with the PUSH/POP values you have used.  Values written to `errno` are defined
in errno.h - or more probably sys/errno.h and you should never conflict with
those numbers.  Moreover, `errno` is used by system and library functions and
I'm not happy extending that for your own private use.

Error handling is often the most difficult part of C (which is perhaps why
exceptions seem at first glance to be such a boon in C++ - although they seem
to cause more problems than they cure from my ignorant perspective).  The
general pattern for library and system functions is to return -1 or NULL to
the caller and maybe set `errno` to show the reason.  Often -1/NULL is
returned in place of the normal return value, which is not ideal.  In your
case, the reason for failure is clear and `errno` is not needed.  As you have
used it, the caller must be sure to set `errno` to zero before calling one of
your functions, as the functions do not indicate failure (even `pop` and `top`
don't, as -1 is a valid number to find on the stack).

So since we don't have exceptions and I'm saying not to use `errno` as you
have, what should you do?

Since you cannot mix the return value and the data (-1 is a valid number for
the stack), there are two alternatives.  Return status and add a return
parameter for the value (pop/top).

```
int push(int *arr, int *length, int data) 
{
    if (*length == MAX_SIZE) {
        return -1;
    }
    arr[(*length)++] = data;
    return 0;
}

int pop(int *arr, int *length, int *data)
{
    if (*length == 0){
        return -1;
    }
    *data = arr[--(*length)];
    return 0;
}
```

Or return the data (pop/top) and add a return parameter for the status:

```
void push(int *arr, int *length, int data, int *status) 
{
    if (*length == MAX_SIZE) {
        *status -1;
    }
    arr[(*length)++] = data;
    *status = 0;
}

int pop(int *arr, int *length, int *status)
{
    if (*length == 0){
        *status -1;
    }
    *status = 0;
    return arr[--(*length)];
}
```

Take your pick and be consistent within the app.  In this case I think I'd go
for returning status.

In the case of your `top` function, you don't need to pass `length` as a
pointer, `arr` could and should be `const` and it is surely not an error if
`length == MAX_SIZE`.

---

**Comments** on 3rd update.

No, as I said before in relation to `errno`, don't use PUSH and POP as error
status. And using `PUSH-1` as a synonym for 0 is horribly wrong.  When you
have defined some constants (with enum or #define etc) you must treat their
value as unknown - **nothing** is permitted to assume the value of an enum or
define - which is what you have done in using `PUSH-1`.  If you assume the
value of such a constant you negate the purpose of using the constant instead
of the raw value.

As I said before, you don't need different status values.  Just use 0 for good
and -1 for bad (or in other circumstances, a valid pointer and NULL, or 1 for true and 0 for false
etc).  If at some point you did need to differentiate between errors, you
could define some error constants. `PUSH` is not an error constant it is one
of your actions. `STACK_FULL` or `STACK_EMPTY` would be meaningful.  But you
**don't** need that here.  Your statements in `main` should just check for
`if (status < 0) {...}` or `if (status != 0) {...}` or even `if (status)
{...}` .

**Comment** on 5th update

That looks much better, don't you think?  I hope you agree because a lot of the process of improving code is self criticism.  Once you get a feeling for what looks good and what  is just not quite right (the 'yuk' feeling), you have made the biggest leap to improving your code.

When I look at your latest update, I now have only minor 'yuk' moments.  One is the START/END tags of the enum, which stick out somehow. I have trouble explaining why - I think it is just at the level of "I wouldn't do that", which is a danger when reviewing - separating objective comments from personal preference.

Another minor point is in your use of START/END.

```
...
} while (!(START < choice && choice < END));
```

This would be more naturally expressed as

```
...
} while (choice <= START || choice >= END);
```

The `peek` function still needs a `const` on `arr` and `length` should not be a pointer.

A final minor point is the return of `enum status` by the functions.  This is perfectly ok.  Nothing wrong at all.  It is just unusual to see functions returning such an enum rather than just an int (0/-1). Arguably what you have is "better" in that it is clear from the enum what is good/bad. It is just not normally done :-)

Comment: Many thanks for the suggestion of `enum`. I always knew that this structure, which I used regularly, was bad but didn't knew any remedy or what to ask for. I'll update my code and post the updated one.

Comment: I added the updated code. Update 2. I haven't taken care of the user experience but I think other things should be good. One thing that I am not sure is the `while` in `get_user_input`. If the things in `enum` become large would checking individually be a good idea? Same goes for using if...else structure in the `main` function. Wouldn't switch work? After all `enum` have `int` associated with them. Please comment.

Comment: I hope you didn't have the time to read the last comment because I tried and the `switch` version worked. I tweaked some more checks and I think the readability increased. Any suggestions?

Comment: About `length == MAX_SIZE` not being an error, in case we are pushing and stack is filled then isn't that an error? I was mistaken in case of function `top` but in case of `push` it is an error. Also I am doing Update 3. Please comment.

Comment: Any comments on update 3?

Comment: Here I don't need more than 1 error state but in the general case if I need to get more than one error states like `Underflow`, `Overflow` then using another `enum` for that is fine?

Comment: @AseemBansal Yes.

Comment: Although I missed the `PUSH - 1` part when I read your code, @WilliamMorris is making a very important point here. `enum`s provide an abstraction, and you should *not* break that abstraction by assuming values. However, as long as the values are contiguous I think it's fine to test if a value is inside the range or not.

Comment: @Lstor I think I fixed it in Update 4. Anything I did wrong in Update 4?

Comment: Your `status` should be an `enum` even though it is just two states. That makes it easier to see if the status means success or failure. In `push`, you are using `START` and `PUSH`, but you should be using status code enums instead.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9892/discussion-between-aseem-bansal-and-lstor)

Answer (score 3):

Most of the code is a driver program. The only really interesting part here is

```
arr[(*length)++] = data;
```

and

```
return arr[--(*length)];
```

as well as the range-checking. I won't look too closely at the driver code.

My key advice is: **Make your data structure reusable.** Put it in a header and implementation file, and use that. The next step is to dynamically allocate the array in a `create` type of function and use that instead.

#### Some general style notes:

- Use (`static`) `const int` instead of `#define` for constants.
- In C99 and C11, you don't have to declare variables at the beginning of a block. Use C99 or C11 and declare variables as late as possible. (You are already using one of them, otherwise your `main` would require a `return 0;` at the end.)
- Don't pass `length` as a pointer. There's no need to, and makes the code more error-prone.
- I like `for (;;)` better than `while (1)`. Think "forever". It's just a matter of taste, though.
- Avoid platform-dependent code. If you must, at least wrap it up in a function.
- Your `push` and `pop` should neither do IO nor exit the program. The C way is to return a status code (or set `errno`).
- Your interface is incomplete: It does not provide a way to *peek* at the top of the stack without popping it.
- In terms of variable names, indentation, whitespace and so on your program is pretty okay. That is good! (But I would have written the extra `ay`.)

These points are mostly nitpicking. Don't bother to improve your program. Write a new one, and take it all the way: **Call `malloc`.**

#### Update: Key points from comments.

- Use a `default` branch in your `switch`. If you don't expect the `default` to ever be entered, then put an assertion in it:

  ```
  switch (condition) {
  case firstCase:
      // ...
  default:
      assert(!"Should never be reached.");
  }
  ```

  String literals are always truthy. By reversing the value (with `!`), the assertion will always trigger if the line is executed.
- `see_top` is often called `peek`.
- The condition in the `do...while` in `get_user_action` can be `choice < PUSH && choice > QUIT`. If you add dummy elements at the beginning and end of the enum and test against them instead, you won't need to update the code when you add more options:

  ```
  enum action { BEGIN, PUSH, /* ... */ END };

  do {
      // ...
  } while (choice <= BEGIN && choice >= END);
  ```
- I'd put an empty line below each case block, and a space before `<` in the `#include`s.
- Sort your `#include`s alphabetically.

Comment: I am going to make it reusable by using pointers. Just wanted to get some basic things out of the way first. If I shouldn't pass the `length` as pointer then how do you propose to update that in the functions? About platform-dependent code, which one? `system('cls')`? The extra `ay`? I am ignoring your advice about `malloc` for now and updating my question with updated code. Please comment.

Comment: I am ignoring the `malloc` part only because I'll be implementing that after I understand completely how to implement stack by arrays. I have been told that my basic concepts are bad so just trying to think everything again.

Comment: Oh, right. I'm too used to having a `struct` to operate on, which would carry the length with it. I mean `system("cls")`, yes. The extra `ay` after `arr`.

Comment: Are there any other suggestions? Also about not having `return 0;` at the end, I have a `return` at the logical end of the program in the `switch` statement.

Comment: I don't have anything further to add to the updated code, except to put `#include <errno.h>` at the top (to keep them sorted alphabetically). Also, I recommend having a `default` branch in your `switch`. In C89, there is no implicit return from `main()`, and therefore you need it right before the end of the scope, unless that is unreachable. But you should prefer C99 or C11 anyway.

Comment: Why use the `default` branch? There doesn't seem to be any use.

Comment: Exactly. Put `assert(!"Should never be reached.");` (or something like that) there, so you will know if you have made a mistake.

Comment: Any comments on update 3?

Comment: Nothing really substantial. `see_top` is often called `peek`. The condition in the `do...while` in `get_user_action` can be `choice < PUSH && choice > QUIT)`. If you add dummy elements at the beginning and end of the `enum` and test against them instead, you won't need to update the code when you add more options. Finally, I'd put an empty line below each `case` block, and a space before `<` in the `#include`s.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9892/discussion-between-aseem-bansal-and-lstor)

Comment: When I asked [this question](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/207272/use-of-const-and-macro-definition-to-declare-constants-in-c-in-what-situations) I came upon [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1674032/static-const-vs-define-in-c) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2308194/shall-i-prefer-constants-over-defines) regarding constants in C. The 2nd one has a better accepted answer but the first one has a better answer.

Comment: They are talking about compile-time constants. In short, if you need the constant at compile-time, use the enum hack. If not, use (`static`) `const`.